# loop through linq return list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have a method as follows

```
public List<viewSearchBook> GetAllBookInfos()
{
    var context = new BookSearchDataClassesDataContext { ObjectTrackingEnabled = false };

    return context.viewSearchBooks.OrderBy(p => p.bookName).ToList();
}
```

In another page I want to fullfill a listview as follows:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var personnelServer = new BookPersonnelServer();
    _dataSource = personnelServer.GetAllBookInfos();

    lsvBookSearch.View = View.Details;

    lsvBookSearch.Columns.Add("bookName");
    lsvBookSearch.Columns.Add("language");
    DataTable tableBookInfo=(Datatable)_dataSource ;

    for (int i = 0; i < tableBookInfo.Rows.Count;i++ )
    {
        lsvBookSearch.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(tableBookInfo.Rows[i]["bookName"]));
        lsvBookSearch.Items[i].SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(tableBookInfo.Rows[i]["language"]));
    }
}
```

_dataSource definition is as follows.

```
private dynamic _dataSource;
```

How to loop through _dataSource.

```
DataTable tableBookInfo=(Datatable)_dataSource ;
```

the above convertion is incorrect.

Comment: Btw, I strongly recommend to make use of the "using" statement for your context! so that it will free resources imediatelly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're assigning to `_dataSource` is a `List<viewSearchBook>`; why do you expect it to be "magically" converted to a `DataTable`? There is no conversion between those types... Why not just loop through the list ?

```
 foreach (viewSearchBook book in _dataSource)
 {
   lsvBookSearch.Items.Add(book.bookName);
   lsvBookSearch.Items[i].SubItems.Add(book.language);
 }
```

And don't declare `_dataSource` as `dynamic`, it doesn't make sense in this case. `dynamic` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.